# The Battleship game: Identify objects within a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, matrix, game

**Toy data**

```
board =
  {{1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9},
   {0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {5, 0, 0, 4, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 8},
   {5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8},
   {5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6},
   {3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}};
```

**Visualization**

```
ArrayPlot[board,
 ColorFunction -> "AtlanticColors",
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {None, Transpose[{Range @ 10, CharacterRange["A", "J"]}]}},
 Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

[Battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game))

is a guessing game for two players. It is played on paper grids on which each player's fleet of warships are marked.  Players shoot at the other player's ships, and the objective of the game is to destroy the opposing player's fleet.

Here we don't want to guess and destroy, but find the ship locations in an elegant mathematical way. In my own coding experiments I got caught up in something that was far too complicated.

**Expected result**

The sorted result should look like:

```
result =
   {"A1:B1", "A3:A6", "A8:B8", "D1:D3", "E6:E7", "F10:J10", "F3:H3", "G1:J1", "J3:J4", "J6:J8"};
```

**Addendum**

There is always some water between the ships, their lengths can range from 2 to 5 square units, and diagonal placements are not allowed.

Comment: two different ships are labeled `3`; is that a typo?

Comment: No, I did that on purpose. Ship identifiers can repeat. Let's say they don't identify the individual ship, but the flag under which it sails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### [NearestNeigborGraph](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeigborGraph.html) + [ConnectedComponents](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedComponents.html)

```
nng = NearestNeighborGraph[Position[board, _Integer?Positive], 
  DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance];

ConnectedComponents[nng] // Column
```

[image]

```
toExcelIndices =  StringRiffle[
  MapAt[ToUpperCase[Alphabet[]][[#]] &, Reverse /@ #, {All, 1}], ":", ""] &

Sort @ Map[toExcelIndices] @ ConnectedComponents[nng][[All, {1, -1}]]
```

> ```
>   {"A1:B1", "A3:A6", "A8:B8", "D1:D3", "E6:E7",   
>    "F10:J10", "F3:H3",   "G1:J1", "J3:J4", "J6:J8"}
> ```

**Visualization:**

```
ap = ArrayPlot[board, 
   ColorFunction -> "AtlanticColors", 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, 
     {None, Transpose[{Range@10, CharacterRange["A", "J"]}]}},
   Mesh -> True
   Epilog ->  MapIndexed[Text[Style[#, 16, White], #2 - 1/2] &, 
      Transpose @ Reverse @ board, {2}]];

nng = Graph[nng,
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   EdgeStyle -> 
    Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[25], Red], 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
     MapApply[-1/2 + {#2, 1 + 10 - #} &] @ GraphEmbedding[nng]];

Show[ap, 
  HighlightGraph[nng, PathGraph /@ ConnectedComponents[nng]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

#### SparseArray + FindClusters

```
shipCoords = FindClusters[
   SparseArray[Transpose @ board]["NonzeroPositions"], 
   DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance];


shipCoords // Column
```

[image]

```
toExcelIndexing = StringRiffle[
   MapAt[ToUpperCase[Alphabet[]][[#]] &, #, {All, 1}], ":", ""] &;

Map[toExcelIndexing] @ shipCoords[[All, {1, -1}]]
```

> ```
> {"A1:B1", "A3:A6", "A8:B8", "D1:D3", "E6:E7", "F3:H3",   
>  "F10:J10", "G1:J1", "J3:J4", "J6:J8"}
> ```

Comment: Nice! [comment padding]

Answer (score 7):

One attempt:

```
board = {
  {1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9}, {0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
, {5, 0, 0, 4, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 8}, {5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8}
, {5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6}
, {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6}, {3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6}
, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}};

{xMax, yMax} = Dimensions@board;
cm = Association@Map[Round
     , ComponentMeasurements[
        MorphologicalComponents[Binarize@Image@board], "BoundingBox"], {-1}];
char = AssociationThread[Range@xMax,Take[ToUpperCase@Alphabet[], xMax]];
coordinates[from : {x0_, y0_}, to : {x1_, y1_}] := 
  StringJoin[Riffle[Sort[
     Map[ToString
     , {{char[x0 + 1], yMax - y0 }, {char[x1], yMax + 1 - y1}}, {2}]], ":"]];
coordinates @@@ cm // Values // Sort
(* Output *)
(*
    {"A1:B1", "A3:A6", "A8:B8", "D1:D3", "E6:E7", "F10:J10", "F3:H3", "G1:J1", "J3:J4", "J6:J8"}
*)
```

Comment: +1 - much to learn for me from your solution

Answer (score 7):

Here is a step-by-step procedure:

```
uniquifiedBoard = MorphologicalComponents[board];
shipIdentifiers = Rest@Union[Flatten[uniquifiedBoard]];
positions = Position[uniquifiedBoard, #] & /@ shipIdentifiers;

(* helpers *)
CreateDescription[pos : {{x_, _} ...}] := {{x, pos[[1, -1]]}, {x, pos[[-1, -1]]}};
CreateDescription[pos : {{_, y_} ...}] := {{pos[[1, 1]], y}, {pos[[-1, 1]], y}};
ExcelifyCoords[{x_, y_}] := Alphabet[][[y]] <> ToString[x];
ExcelifyRange[{a_List, ___List, b_List}] := ExcelifyCoords[a] <> ":" <> ExcelifyCoords[b];

(* result *)
ExcelifyRange /@ positions

(* 
  {"a1:b1", "a3:a6", "a8:b8", "d1:d3", "e6:e7", "f10:j10", "f3:h3", "g1:j1", "j3:j4", "j6:j8"}
 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

This should, at least and at last, convince me to start learning about graphs.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
board = {{1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9}, {0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {5, 0, 0, 4, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 8}, {5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    8}, {5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    6}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6}, {3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    6}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3}};

across = (Transpose[{ToUpperCase@Alphabet[][[1 ;; Length@#]], #}] & /@
         board /. {a_, 0} :> Nothing // 
      Map[GatherBy[#, Last] &]) /. {{a_, b_}} :> Nothing // 
   MapIndexed[
     ToString@First@First@#1 <> ToString@First@#2 <> ":" <> 
       ToString@First@Last@#1 <> ToString@First@#2 &, #, {2}] & // 
  Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> {"A1:B1", "G1:J1", "F3:H3", "A8:B8", "F10:J10"}

```
down = (Transpose[{ToUpperCase@
            Alphabet[][[1 ;; Length@#]], #}] & /@ (Transpose@
          board) /. {a_, 0} :> Nothing // Map[GatherBy[#, Last] &]) //
    Map[Replace[#, {{a_, b_}} :> Nothing, {1}] &] //
   MapIndexed[
     ToUpperCase@FromLetterNumber@First@#2 <> 
       ToString@LetterNumber@First@First@#1 <> ":" <> 
       ToUpperCase@FromLetterNumber@First@#2 <> 
       ToString@LetterNumber@First@Last@#1 &, #, {2}] & // 
  Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> {"A3:A6", "D1:D3", "E6:E7", "J3:J4", "J6:J8"}

Comment: Your preface to the answer had me down in tears XD

Answer (score 4):

#### MapIndexed + SplitBy

```
ClearAll[indexBoard, bowStern, findShips]

ucA = ToUpperCase@Alphabet[];

indexBoard[direction_ : "Across"] := Module[
   {d$ = direction /. {"Across" -> Reverse, _ -> Identity}}, 
   MapIndexed[If[# == 0, Nothing, 
      {#, StringRiffle[{ucA[[#]], #2} & @@ d$[#2], ""]}] &, #, {2}]] &

bowStern = Map[
     Splice @
     Cases[{{_, f_}, ___, {_, l_}} :> StringRiffle[{f, l}, ":"]] @
     SplitBy[#, First] &];

findShips = Sort @ Map[Splice @* bowStern] @
   {indexBoard[] @ #, indexBoard["Down"] @ Transpose @ #} &;


findShips @ board
```

> ```
>   {"A1:B1", "A3:A6", "A8:B8", "D1:D3", "E6:E7", "F10:J10",   
>    "F3:H3", "G1:J1", "J3:J4", "J6:J8"}
> ```